# How to convert the data from horizontal to vertical in excel

Tags: excel

In excel I want to convert the data as shown in the below image. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy the data.

Select first cell of destination area.

Then use « edit - paste special » and check the transpose box.

Comment: Thank you . But have 3000 such supplier no so doing for each will be difficult.

Comment: Then use a macro to run the same process.

Comment: If you don’t have any macro experience, then use the record macro button and then edit it to get what you need. You can also find examples that may help you on here.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have experience in macro will try to learn from examples.

Comment: Also is there any formula which can convert the data as mentioned in my question?

Comment: You can search for a formula on here as that has been asked before.